# Spring: how to execute `@Sql` within the transaction of test method?

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I need the following logic:
1. Test method starts
2. Transaction opens
3. Prepare SQL file is executed
4. Test method is processed
5. Transaction rollbacks

My test class is annotated with

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
```

I tried to use `@org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql` before test method but it doesn't work - looks like it opens a transaction, executes SQL, closes transaction (reverts it?) and after that starts test. A test doesn't see changes from SQL file

My question is: how to execute `@org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql` within the transaction of test method? Any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 12):

You should have a look at the `config` property of the `@Sql` annotation, there it is possible to specify the `TransactionMode` to be used.

So for instance the following scripts are executed in a separate transaction ahead of entering the test method:

```
@Sql(
  scripts = {"classpath:file1.sql", "classpath:file2.sql"},
  config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = TransactionMode.ISOLATED))
@Test
public void foo() { ... }
```

Comment: Good spot! I've been having issues with `@Transactional` and `@Sql`. I managed to get it sorted after using `TransactionMode.ISOLATED`.

Answer (score 1):

`@Sql` annotation works as expected. I had another problem - my tested method opened new Thread which didn't see changes from test transaction